# Debugging ASP.NET website from Visual Studio causes restart of the website

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, restart

Somehow, since some time I'm experiencing problems with debugging my ASP.NET website.
Every time I try to debug the website ASP.NET shuts down (global.asax_Application_End is called).
I believe this is triggered because the site is built by Visual Studio. However, manually (re)build the site and then start debugging also restarts the site. Even debugging and ending the debugging session, clicking a couple of buttons on the site to get to the desired state, and start a debugging session again still triggers a build action, which causes the site to restart.
Since restarting resets HttpRuntime.Cache booting the site takes a long time, and sometimes I want to debug some situation that involves caching.

Now there is a setting on the website's property pages:
Start Action (F5):
Before running startup page:
No Build / Build Page / Build Web Site.

I've set it to No Build, restarted Visual Studio, but still it triggers the build action every time I hit F5 or the Start debugging button...

Anyone any ideas as to how to resolve this??

Thanks,

Jaap

Answer (score 0):

We've solved this by converting our project to a Web Application instead of a Web Site. This had some impact on our architecture since we had some classes in app_code which we needed to use reflection on during site startup.
It turns out that the Web application in combination with "Use Custom Web Server" fixed out issue!